# Unexpected vs missing parenthesis problem

Tags: powershell, debugging, syntax

Despite spending ages on trying to debug this error message, I cannot resolve it and am hoping another pair of eyes can spot where the error is. When running the PowerShell script via Windows PowerShell, I am presented with this error message:

[image]

It is complaining about an "unexpected token '}'" on the last line below where there is a closing parenthesis, but as far as I can tell, this shouldn't be an error as it is required to close the opening parenthesis on the first line:

```
foreach ($auditlogitem in $aggregateResults) {
    $datum = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    $d=convertfrom-json $auditlogitem.AuditData
    if ($datum -AND $d ) {
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Id -Value $d.Id
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CreationDateTime –Value $auditlogitem.CreationDate
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CreationTimeUTC –Value $d.CreationTime
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name RecordType –Value $d.RecordType
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Operation –Value $d.Operation
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OrganizationId –Value $d.OrganizationId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserType –Value $d.UserType
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserKey –Value $d.UserKey
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Workload –Value $d.Workload
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserId –Value $d.UserId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ClientIP –Value $d.ClientIP
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserAgent –Value $d.UserAgent
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Activity –Value $d.Activity
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ItemName –Value $d.ItemName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name WorkSpaceName –Value $d.WorkSpaceName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DashboardName –Value $d.DashboardName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DatasetName –Value $d.DatasetName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ReportName –Value $d.ReportName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name WorkspaceId –Value $d.WorkspaceId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ObjectId –Value $d.ObjectId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DashboardId –Value $d.DashboardId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DatasetId –Value $d.DatasetId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ReportId –Value $d.ReportId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OrgAppPermission –Value $d.OrgAppPermission
        #option to include the below JSON column however for large amounts of data it may be difficult for PBI to parse
        #$datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Datasets –Value (ConvertTo-Json $d.Datasets)
        
        #below is a simple PowerShell statement to grab one of the entries and place in the DatasetName if any exist
        foreach ($dataset in $d.datasets) {
            $datum.DatasetName = $dataset.DatasetName
            $datum.DatasetId = $dataset.DatasetId
        }
        $data+=$datum
    }
}
```

If I remove the closing/last parenthesis, it complains of a missing parenthesis but if I don't remove it, it complains of an unexpected parenthesis!

If I remove this entire code block from the program, then it executes fine so I'm fairly confident that the problem is within the above block of code.

**Full program:**

```
#Audit Logs 

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

#Better for scheduled jobs
$User = "dcdc@M365x07sx3547.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "e2asxsxsx4DWR" -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

#This will prompt the user for credential (optional)
#$UserCredential = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session

$startDate=(get-date).AddDays(-5)
$endDate=(get-date)
$scriptStart=(get-date)

$sessionName = (get-date -Format 'u')+'pbiauditlog'
# Reset user audit accumulator
$aggregateResults = @()
$i = 0 # Loop counter
Do { 
    $currentResults = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $enddate -SessionId $sessionName -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -ResultSize 1000 -RecordType PowerBIAudit
    if ($currentResults.Count -gt 0) {
        Write-Host ("  Finished {3} search #{1}, {2} records: {0} min" -f [math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start $scriptStart).TotalMinutes,4), $i, $currentResults.Count, $user.UserPrincipalName )
        # Accumulate the data
        $aggregateResults += $currentResults
        # No need to do another query if the # recs returned <1k - should save around 5-10 sec per user
        if ($currentResults.Count -lt 1000) {
            $currentResults = @()
        } else {
            $i++
        }
    }
} Until ($currentResults.Count -eq 0) # --- End of Session Search Loop --- #

$data=@()

foreach ($auditlogitem in $aggregateResults) {
    $datum = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    $d=convertfrom-json $auditlogitem.AuditData
    if ($datum -AND $d ) {
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Id -Value $d.Id
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CreationDateTime –Value $auditlogitem.CreationDate
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CreationTimeUTC –Value $d.CreationTime
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name RecordType –Value $d.RecordType
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Operation –Value $d.Operation
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OrganizationId –Value $d.OrganizationId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserType –Value $d.UserType
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserKey –Value $d.UserKey
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Workload –Value $d.Workload
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserId –Value $d.UserId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ClientIP –Value $d.ClientIP
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserAgent –Value $d.UserAgent
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Activity –Value $d.Activity
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ItemName –Value $d.ItemName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name WorkSpaceName –Value $d.WorkSpaceName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DashboardName –Value $d.DashboardName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DatasetName –Value $d.DatasetName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ReportName –Value $d.ReportName
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name WorkspaceId –Value $d.WorkspaceId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ObjectId –Value $d.ObjectId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DashboardId –Value $d.DashboardId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DatasetId –Value $d.DatasetId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ReportId –Value $d.ReportId
        $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OrgAppPermission –Value $d.OrgAppPermission
        #option to include the below JSON column however for large amounts of data it may be difficult for PBI to parse
        #$datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Datasets –Value (ConvertTo-Json $d.Datasets)
        
        #below is a simple PowerShell statement to grab one of the entries and place in the DatasetName if any exist
        foreach ($dataset in $d.datasets) {
            $datum.DatasetName = $dataset.DatasetName
            $datum.DatasetId = $dataset.DatasetId
        }
        $data+=$datum
    }
}

$datestring = $startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$fileName = ($datestring + ".csv")
Write-Host ("Writing to file {0}" -f $fileName) 

if ($data) {
    $data | Export-csv $fileName
}

#File transfer to Azure storage account 
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $UserCredential
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Audit" -status | Export-Csv "$Env:temp/AuditLogs.csv"
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "storageaccountname" -StorageAccountKey "FccC+Ev3m+kjnaslkdcjnlaksjcndlkasjdn5XErWQ1sgsmPxhjpn3M5ew=="
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Force -Context $Context -Container "auditlogs" -File $filename -Blob $filename 

#Close PowerShell session
Remove-PSSession -Id $Session.Id
```

Comment: I don't get any mismatches (PS 5.1).  Bracket pairs are 1/39, 4/38, 33/36

Comment: The error message you showed was for line 79, which means there's more in the file than just this and therefore, more opportunities for mismatches.  Without the rest of the file, there's not much we can do.

Comment: The sample you've provided is syntactically valid - what about the preceding ~40 lines of code?

Comment: I've added in the full set of code for the program. Please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @MAK Assuming you haven't used dummy values, that password and storage key need to be changed _right now_, just FYI. But I'm afraid there's still nothing in the full code sample that would explain the error you're seeing

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for taking a look anyway. Man, this is frustrating. 

PS. Yes I have used dummy values for the code, but thanks for looking out :)

Comment: With the new code, there isn't even a bracket on line 79...

Comment: The line in the error message isn’t always the line where the error actually occurs - it’s just the line where the parser gave up trying to match braces. To narrow the problem down, try making a copy of your script and removing chunks of the code until the error disappears, then slowly and bits of it back until it re-appears. The last bit you added will be where the problem is...

Comment: weirdly, the error seems to be in the line ```$datum = New-Object –TypeName PSObject``` - if you comment that out it parses fine. I haven't had time to check, but maybe there's a special non-printing character hiding in there somewhere?

Comment: Ah, it's the hypen in ```-TypeName``` - it's a ```–``` (em-dash) in your code, but replace it with ```-``` (en-dash) and it'll work fine.

Comment: @mclayton, that's it! 

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's the hypen in *-TypeName*

It's an – (em-dash) in my code, but if I replace it with - (en-dash), it works fine!

Answer posted by mclayton: [Unexpected vs missing parenthesis problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671105/unexpected-vs-missing-parenthesis-problem#comment112596751_63671105)